# Jewish Law in Employer/employee relationships

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, employment, beit-din-court

I saw, in an article on ["Halachic Considerations of Firing Employees"](http://www.thehalachacenter.org/at_a_glance/5771_reeh.php) by Rav Dovid Grossman of The Bais HaVaad Halacha Center:

> Hagaon Rav Moshe Feinstein Zt"l writes a tremendous chiddush in regards to firing employees who are not classified as an Ani. He writes, that any time a worker is hired without term, it is as if they were hired **forever**. Therefore, unless you cannot afford to keep them as employees, they are not qualified for the job, or another new cause exists making it impossible to keep the worker, the employer simply can **never** fire them. Consequently, even if the boss would like to take his relative into the business, or a more qualified replacement is found (assuming the current employee is also considered qualified, albeit not as qualified), the employee cannot be fired. Therefore, if the boss needs the work done, and this employee can effectively perform this work, he must be kept on the payroll. The Chazon Ish and others argue and allow a boss to fire any employee who is not under contract. Wherever possible, one should be Machmir like Rav Moshe Zt"l.

(emphases his)

Is this prohibition actionable in Beit Din by someone who believes that he was unjustly fired by an employer who's also an observant Jew? How would one go about bringing such a case to Beit Din?

The type of case I have in mind: A person is being fired / demoted at the age of 66, one year away from retirement. This person has had no verbal or written reprimands, and, in fact, has received bonuses every year for good work. Both the employee and employer are observant Jews.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Could you please [edit] to explain why you think the employee could take the employer to Beit Din, and what the case would be?

Comment: Employee is essentially being forced into early retirement because he is a senior manager and not employable elsewhere at the age of 66. Furthermore, no reason for termination has been given

Comment: @yagoodi Careful that this isn't a request for psak (RFP). The details of your question are VERY specific. Regardless, why couldn't the employee go to B"D? The worst that could happen is that they disagree with the assessment. Thing is, AFAIK there's no discussion/halachic source for age discrimination, so at best this would be a violation of acting dishonestly (והייתם נקיים ), but CYLOR.

Comment: I am asking just that...Can this issue be taken to a Beit Din and how does one go about doing this?

Comment: But what halacha might he be not following?

Comment: Hagaon Rav Moshe Feinstein Zt writes that any time a worker  is hired without term, it is as if they were hired forever.unless you cannot afford to keep them or they are not qualified for the job, the employer can never fire them.Even if the boss would like to take his relative into the business, or a more qualified replacement is found   the employee cannot be fired. Therefore, if the boss needs the work done, and this employee can effectively perform this work, he must be kept on the payroll.whenever possible, one should be Machmir like Rav Moshe Zt�l.

Comment: I've [edit]ed that information into the question itself, as it is important motivation for why you're asking. By the way, i almost didn't see your comment. When you reply to someone, you should ping them (@IsaacKotlicky, for example) so that they get a message.

Comment: @Scimonster I think the part you edited into the question is really an answer.

Comment: @Scimonster I would add the additional parameter of Dina DiMalchusa Dina, which would imply that age discrimination (being illegal in America) is therefore against halacha. While proving discrimination is generally difficult, a record of stellar performance ending in termination without cause (especially if the only other people let go were similarly nearing retirement) is pretty telling. Here's a link with more details: http://www.eeoc.gov/laws/types/age.cfm

Comment: Do you known where this halacha from R Moshe is written? It certainly sounds interesting

Comment: Were you quoting that from [here](http://www.thehalachacenter.org/at_a_glance/5771_reeh.php)? It looks like a lot of the same words.... (cc @Scimonster)

Comment: Yes, that is where I was quating from. I had to paraphrase because of the limit on words.

Comment: I did my best to incorporate the motivating quotation as well as [this clarifying comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61395/jewish-law-in-employer-employee-relationships#comment167279_61395)  while generalizing a little bit more, so that it's clearly not a request for psak on a specific case. Please feel free to [edit] further if I've deviated from your intent. Thanks very much for bringing this interesting question here. I look forward to seeing you around. You might be interested in taking a look at some of our hundred other [tag:employement] questions.

Answer (score 2):

He could try, but I doubt he'd get very far.

Rabbi Michael Broyde has written and spoken about this. Unless otherwise specified, we assume agreements are done *k'minhag hamedina*, according to the prevailing local practice. In the US, at least, employment is generally "at-will", which means a worker can be laid off with not justification needed.

The one exception is a longstanding tradition we have regarding severance pay for jobs of a religious nature, e.g. a rabbi or Judaics teacher. ([*Brisman vs. HAFTR*](http://www.courts.state.ny.us/REPORTER/3dseries/2010/2010_01480.htm) addressed this, especially as the teacher's contract stipulated that the Beth Din of America would handle disputes. The Beth Din ruled that halacha stipulates strong employment protection for Judaics teachers, and on appeal, the courts upheld that as an arbitration agreement.)

Here's the [contact info for the Beth Din of America](http://www.bethdin.org/contact.asp); but absent anything stipulated, unless the job title is religious in nature, I doubt anything would come of it.

Comment: The OP hasn't stated this is the USA. Looking things up retirement age in the USA is 66 at present, but in Israel is 67. So maybe this is Israel?

Comment: yes, it is Israel. Good call